# Select a specific menu item from a Windows context (right-click) menu using VBScript?

Tags: windows, windows-7, vbscript, cloud

Is there a way that I could automate the right-clicking of a file in a Windows 7 folder and select the, "Send To -> Amazon Cloud Drive" context menu option in a simple VB script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes and no.  There is no direct way of doing this.  You could create a workaround but it would be very involved.

The "proper" approach is to use the ShellFolderItem object's `InvokeVerb` method.  It looks like this:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace("C:")
Set objFile = objFolder.ParseName("test.vbs")

' Execute context menu item
'objFile.InvokeVerb("&Copy")

' List all possible verbs
Set colFolderItemVerbs = objFile.Verbs

For Each objFolderItemVerb in colFolderItemVerbs
    WScript.Echo Chr(34) & objFolderItemVerb.Name & Chr(34)
Next
```

The problem is that submenu items are listed as empty strings.

As one possible workaround is to navigate to the Send To folder and grab the command line for the shortcut you want to use.  You could then implement it directly.

Comment: This is old but when I go through the `echo`... it's missing Pin to Taskbar.